# {N} 6 breaks google maps info windows on iOS

Tags: ios, nativescript, google-maps-markers

After upgrading to NativeScript 6, tapping a marker on a google map on iOS to display the associated info window crashes the app.  This is due to _layoutRootView being removed - see nativescript-google-maps-sdk issue 354 at https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/issues/354

The problem is that no alternative is provided, and the google-maps-sdk plugin has not had any recent activity.

I post this to SO to notify the larger NativeScript community and to understand if there are any alternatives.

The error message shown is

```
JavaScript error:
file:///node_modules/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/map-view.js:164:30: JS ERROR TypeError: __webpack_require__("../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/utils.js").ios._layoutRootView is not a function. (In '__webpack_require__("../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/utils.js").ios._layoutRootView(content, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height))', '__webpack_require__("../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/utils.js").ios._layoutRootView' is undefined)
```

[edit]

Following the direction from @manoj I manually copied the code for _layoutRootView in both tns-core-modules/ui/utils.d.ts and tns-core-modules/ui/utils.ios.js from another project using {N} 5.3.  Info windows on iOs now work!!

I fully get that editing code in node-modules is a bad idea, but I could never get around webpack errors using Manoj's approach.  Is there a better way to add a function to a NativeScript module from within my own javascript project?

Comment: A hot fix could be appending the removed method (_layoutRootView) back in utils module.

Comment: @manoj OK, I'm open to that, as I really need this to work.  Can you elaborate on what you mean by "appending the removed method"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import * as utils from 'tns-core-modules/utils/utils';

if (utils.ios) {
    (<any>utils.ios)._layoutRootView = function(rootView, parentBounds) {
        if (!rootView || !parentBounds) {
            return;
        }

        const size = parentBounds.size;
        const width = utils.layout.toDevicePixels(size.width);
        const height = utils.layout.toDevicePixels(size.height);

        const widthSpec = utils.layout.makeMeasureSpec(width, utils.layout.EXACTLY);
        const heightSpec = utils.layout.makeMeasureSpec(height, utils.layout.EXACTLY);

        rootView.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

        const origin = parentBounds.origin;
        const left = origin.x;
        const top = origin.y;

        rootView.layout(left, top, width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much!  I converted to plain javascript added this code to my map-page.js file but get this message: JavaScript error:
file:///node_modules/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/map-view.js:164:30: JS ERROR TypeError: __webpack_require__("../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/utils.js").ios._layoutRootView is not a function. (In '__webpack_require__("../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/utils.js").ios._layoutRootView(content, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height))', '__webpack_require__("../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/utils.js").ios._layoutRootView' is undefined)
NativeScript caught signal 11.

Comment: I changed back to the original import statement (had been using 'require') and no longer receive the web pack error, but the map that's displayed is the full world map with none of my lines or markers.  Investigating further...

Comment: See my edit to the original post.  I manually copied the code for _layoutRootView and it worked.  Can this be done from within a javascript project?